# How to fix "The target [...] is declared multiple times" after pod install?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Working on a react-native(version 0.59.5) project, just installed cocoapods(version 1.7.5)

Installation process:

(from within project directory)

-`sudo gem install cocoapods`

(from within iOS directory of project)

-`pod init`

-`pod install --repo-update`

Result:

`Analyzing Dependencies`
`[!] The Target 'ProjectName-tvOSTests' is declared multiple times.`

then tried `pod update` which resulted in the same 'Analyzing Dependencies' warning. There is only a Podfile and a 'Pods' directory in iOS directory. the pods directory has three sub-directories which are all empty. It seems there was a hangup during `pod install` but I don't know where to look for the duplicate declaration.

I'm aware you should be working from within the ProjectName.xcworkspace file after a installing cocoapods, but there is no .xcworkspace file in my iOS directory of project. How do I fix this?

EDIT:

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TicTacWHOA' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TicTacWHOA
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

  target 'TicTacWHOA-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TicTacWHOATests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  end

end

target 'TicTacWHOA-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TicTacWHOA-tvOS

  target 'TicTacWHOA-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post the code that is contained in your podfile

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: target 'TicTacWHOA-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

remove this piece of code once

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue was that the "Target" was literally declared twice in the Podfile. so simple and right in front of your face potentially. I Just didn't think anything of it because it was a completely generated file except the one line I added.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is go to podfile and look for the code in the error
for example my error was

**[!] The target `fifty-tvOSTests` is declared multiple times.**

now i have deleted this piece of code from the podfile once.

```
target 'fifty-tvOSTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing 
end
```

fifty is the name of my project you know well what is yours
the above piece of code was twice in the Podfile so delete if you find multiple just keep only once